# FFmpeg is not working with the media file path containing whitespace in name

Tags: react-native, ffmpeg

I am using react-native-ffmpeg with react native for basic video editing, however I am facing this issue if a media file uri contain whitespace then ffmpeg task failed with error message "No such file or directory".

**I have tried:**

1. RNFmeg.executeWithArguments but app crashes without any error message. Here is my command array.

   RNFFmpeg.executeWithArguments(["-i", videoPath, "-i", songPath, "-c:v", "copy", "-c:a", "aac", "-map", "0:v:0", "-map", "1:a:0", "-t", duration, `${path}${timeStamp}.mp4`])
2. One other solution I do'nt want to go with is to copy the media file which I have picked from device local storage to cache directory with new name eliminating whitespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working solution**

The parameters apparently needs to be strings to guarantee that they work correctly.  The `-t` parameter (`duration`) had to be converted to a string, as discovered by Kamran Ashiq

**Alternate suggestion (shouldn't be the case with this framwork, but useful general solution)**

What's most likely happening is that ffmpeg sees the space as a separator for more parameters, such as multiple files.

You should be able to either quote or escape the path, so ffmpeg sees it as just one parameter instead of multiple.

E.g., when calling it on the command line one would either do:

```
$ ffmpeg -some -parameters "foo bar.mp4"
# or
$ ffmpeg -some -parameters foo\ bar.mp4
```

Similar in your code you should probably do:

```js
RNFFmpeg.executeWithArguments(["-i", videoPath, "-i", songPath, "-c:v", "copy", "-c:a", "aac", "-map", "0:v:0", "-map", "1:a:0", "-t", duration, `"${path}${timeStamp}.mp4"`])
```

Comment: Tried still no luck. React native package for ffmpeg handle uri with spaces in command array other than just a single quoted string, I have been able to run a simple command on a uri containing spaces successfully. I think problem lies in the command argument i posted.

Comment: Three suggestions then, try to remove all parameters except the file and see if it works, if it does add the parameters one by one. Two see if you can get it to log the exact command executed to see if the problem is apparent. Last, if you use relative paths, try an absolute path, just in case :)

Comment: Yes the problem was with the -t duration parameter as it was an integer after converting it to string it worked.

Comment: Cool, do you prefer to create and answer yourself or should I edit mine to reflect what you found?

Comment: can we write `"-c:a", "aac"` as `"-c:a, aac"` or `"-c:a aac"`??

Comment: @VivekThummar judging from the discovery that Kamran Ashiq made, I suspect you can't. Not sure why you'd want that either, keeping it like arrays gives the huge advantage that the framework can take care of escapes for you in a consistent and predictable way

Comment: @VivekThummar you can'nt, purpose is to write key pair(params) separately in the command array.

Comment: @Rohde Fischer Sure you can edit your one.